# Изменение блоков с таблицой по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Не знаю смогу ли объяснить мою проблему, но попробую:
Схематично: [макет](https://prnt.sc/ptb3xq)

т.е. у меня есть слева меню, по середине контент и справа таблица на которой расположена стрелка, при клике на которую таблица открывается на всю ширину до левого меню поверх контента, и стрелка переворачивается в другую сторону, а по клику на нее опять возвращается в исходное положение и таблица и стрелка анимированно (плавно в общем).
Изначально начал вот так и на первом этапе вошел в ступор:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button-change-table-moneyback').click(function () {
    
        if (($("#button-change-table-moneyback").hasClass('first-state-of-the-button')) && ($("#table").hasClass('first-state-table'))){
        
            $("#button-change-table-moneyback").addClass('second-state-of-the-button');
            
            $("#table").addClass('second-state-of-the-table');
            
        }else {
        
        ($("#button-change-table-moneyback").addClass('first-state-of-the-button')){
        
            $("#table").addClass('first-state-of-the-table');;
            
            console.log('back1');
        }
    });
     
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}

.left-menu{
  border: 3px solid gray;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100px;
}

.content{
  border: 3px solid green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
}

#table{

}

.first-state-of-the-table{
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.second-state-of-the-table{
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#button-change-table-moneyback{
    cursor: pointer;
    left: -35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    /* transform: rotate(180deg); */
}

.first-state-of-the-button{
    left: -35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: all .9s;
}

.second-state-of-the-button{
    left: -35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transition: all .9s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-menu">left-menu</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div id="table" class="table first-state-of-the-table">table
        <div id="button-change-table-moneyback" class="first-state-of-the-button">
          <img src="https://dtraduga.by/media/system/images/arrow.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: При клике на кнопку колонка left-menu и content должны скрываться, а стрелка переворачиваться? при повторном нажатии они появляются и стрелка возвращается в исходное состояние?

Comment: нет, меню левое остается, просто таблица плавно растягивается до левого меню перекрывая весь контент между ними (поверх всего короче) и в этот момент стрелка переворачивается в противоположную сторону, - при втором клике таблица и стрелка возвращаются в начальное положение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#button-change-table-moneyback').click(() => {
  $('.left-menu, .content').toggle();
  $('#button-change-table-moneyback').toggleClass('second-state-of-the-button');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.left-menu {
  border: 3px solid gray;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100px;
}

.content {
  border: 3px solid green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
}

#table {
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
     }

.first-state-of-the-table {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.second-state-of-the-table {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#button-change-table-moneyback {
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  /* transform: rotate(180deg); */
}

.first-state-of-the-button {
  left: -35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all .9s;
}

.second-state-of-the-button {
  left: -35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all .9s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-menu">left-menu</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div id="table" class="table first-state-of-the-table">table
    <div id="button-change-table-moneyback" class="first-state-of-the-button">
      <img src="https://dtraduga.by/media/system/images/arrow.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да все круто как у вас, только до левого меню и анимированно  (плавно)

Comment: Уберите меню  `$('.content').toggle();`

Comment: убрал, теперь работает до бокового  меню, но непонятно почему при открытии таблицы на весь экран - скачет левое меню по ширине, а плавно с анимацией не получается сделать... вешаю на состояния  transition: all .9s; - но никакой реакции
https://jsfiddle.net/AlexGood2016/7yf23bL0/65/

Comment: Можно добавить класс где ширина будет 0, примерно так:

`
$('.content').toggleClass('tr');`



`.tr{
width: 0px;
transition: all .9s
}`